# LOAD DATA INFILE error issues

Tags: mysql

Here is my code and I keep getting an error and do not know the reason.  I am trying to convert my code to use the load data infile rather than doing a loop with the insert into so it will run faster.  I can insert into on this just fine but when I try to do the load data infile it doesnt seem to work.

Here is the error message: Could not load. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
//mysql login creds
$username = "root";
$password = "XXXX";
$hostname = "localhost";


//This is the var that holds the connection
$earthScores = file_get_contents('earthfeed.txt', 'r');

//mysql connection
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select DB to work with
mysql_select_db("eetoolsx_earthfeed",$conn)
or die("Could not select alliance_news_feed");

//clear table before writing new
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE scores');

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$earthScores'" .
                  " INTO TABLE scores FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','");

if(!$result){
   die("Could not load. " .mysql_error());
}



mysql_close($conn);


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I use this code it doent give me an access denied error:

$query = "INSERT INTO scores (serverid,resetid,      rank,number,countryname,land,networth,tag,gov,gdi,protection,vacation,alive,deleted)
   VALUES ('$str[$a]','$str[$b]','$str[$c]','$str[$d]','$str[$e]','$str[$f]','$str[$g]','$str[$h]',
   '$str[$i]','$str[$j]','$str[$k]','$str[$l]','$str[$m]','$str[$n]')";

mysql_query($query,$conn);

Comment: Why are you expecting an error with this other query?

Comment: If you won't believe @JimLewis then have a look at the manual chapter [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) please. Fixing your error and accepting Jims answer would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` expects a filename, but you're passing it the file *contents*.